# Want to get the number of months through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the number of months between two dates with JavaScript, but if the number of **days** greater than 30 days or greater than 1 month then it directly return me two months.

For example if my from date is 17/01/2011 and to date is 20/02/2011 then my function returns two months because then days between two days exceeds one month.

Hope you all understand.

Comment: But if the first date is 17/01/2011 and the next one is 21/07/2012 should it still return 2 months?  Or do you just want it to round up the number of months?

Comment: @user535617 No at this time it returns 7 months instead of 6 months because the days are exceed then 6 months exactly. means round up the number of months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Mootools [Date.diff](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Date#Date:diff).  If you're tied to jQuery, you could instead refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery) on Stack Overflow.